# Number of possible roots for a finite degree polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I know that polynomial (in a single variable) over any field has at most $n$ roots where $n$ is degree of the polynomial and in $\mathbb C$ it has exactly $n$ roots.

Now if coefficients are in any ring not a field, then any $n$ degree can have more than $n$ roots may have more roots, example $x^2=I_2$ in $M_2(\mathbb R)$ has $4$ roots

\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}

> Now my question is whether there exists a ring in which a finite degree polynomial has infinitely many roots.

Comment: Polynomials of degree $n$ over the quaternion algebra can have infinitely many roots.

Comment: In fact your own equation $x^2 = I_2$ in $M_2(\mathbb R)$ already has infinitely many roots: any reflection in a line through the origin gives a solution (since reflecting twice is the same as doing nothing), and there are infinitely many such lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of solutions may be infinite. In the ring of quaternions, if $\theta$ is a real number then $(i\cos\theta+j\sin \theta)^2+1=0$ because $i^2=j^2=-1$ and $i j+j i=0.$

Comment: @254665 thanks ,.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$$\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}$$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$For a commutative example, in the ring
$$
\prod_{i \in \N} B_{i},
$$
where each $B_{i}$ is a copy of the integers $\Z$, the polynomial $x^{2} - 1$ has the infinitely many roots
$$
(\epsilon_{i})_{i \in \N},
$$
where $\epsilon_{i} \in \Set{1, -1}$.

Comment: Here i think roots are uncountable, same as sequence of $0$ and $1$ uncountable.

Comment: Yes, $2^{\aleph_{0}}$.

Comment: yes exactly, thanks

Comment: Good one.+1............What's interesting about the quaternions is that it is a division ring: $ab\ne 0 $ if $a\ne 0\ne b$.In a ring with divisors of $0$ the equation $x^2=0$ might have any finite or infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @user254665, for instance in a product of copies of the integers modulo $4$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti. This suggests a Q in ring theory, which it not  a subject I know very much. If $R$ is a ring (with identity) and $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ over $f$ with no $0$, can $R$ be embedded in a ring $R^*$ in which $f$ has at least $n$ zeroes?

Comment: @user254665 The polynomial $2x+1\in\mathbb Z_4[x]$ has no root in *every* ring extension of $\mathbb Z_4$ (why?).

Comment: I suppose because if there is $x_{0}$ such that $2 x_{0} + 1 = 0$, then multiplying by $2$ one gets $2 = 0$.

Comment: @user26857 .Thanks. Very clear.